# Common File System Attributes on Linux, Mac and Windows

Tags: linux, windows, macos, filesystems

I am looking for the some document/presentation which will give me an idea about different File and Directory attributes available on Windows, Mac and Linux file system. Also wanted to know Common attributes present across all three Operating systems. I want to cross verify my work.

Thanks,
Omky

Answer (score 2):

First, you want to check the File system rather the OS, is mostly a File system feature, not OS, the Operative System can "support" or not all FS features.

On Linux and OSX, there is a UNIX standard, you have the common owner/group/other where a File contains a user owner (just a user) and a group owner (a group contains a list of users).

With that knowledge, you can set permissions like read/write/executable permissions for the owner of file, the group of file and a "non user non member of the group".

Example:

I have a file called hello.out and I want to restrict a "modification" for EVERY user, but my user only can execute it and every user can read it. I will set permission 544. the first value, 5 will provide read and execute to owner, the second value, 4 will provide only read to group, and the third value, another 4, will provide only read to any other user.

You have extended permissions on some UNIX file systems, on EXT2/3/4 and others, you can set permissions for a specific user (File system extended attributes). Also, you have some "flags" with special features, like provide a root execution with the SUID flag or force exclusivity of files on a directory to owner with the sticky flag.

More info about UNIX permissions here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions

On Windows instead, is hard to say, first, you have FAT16/32, there is no permissions with this File system. Using FAT16/32 on Linux can "emulate" a UNIX permission, but is global for all files and will not be stored on File system.

For File systems like NTFS, is pretty similar to UNIX, but you have a longer list of control for actions on the file or folder, but basically you have read/write/read and execute/list files/modify/full permission.

For more info, you can find every basic and special attributes here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx